# Store all the queries executed in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, auditing

How can i store all queries including select query in user defined table considering auditing is not enabled for select queries and we cannot enable it too.

Comment: will you please elaborate what are you trying to say?

Comment: Why is it you cannot enable AUDIT, but yet you are able (allowed?) to grow your own audit functionality?  This sounds like yet another x-y problem. What is the business problem being solved by storing "all queries including select query"?  What decisions will be based on this stored information?

Comment: Whatever query we are executing in SQL we want to insert it in a table and then create a log file and delete from table or create a log file without storing it in table. This is for internal purpose not a requirement by client thus we cannot enable auditing for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Select Event Handler to store the queries executed.
A Handler can be used for Select Events on multiple Tables or Views, you can do anything you like